# Shall i handle the Java RuntimeException?

Tags: java, exception

Is it good to handle `UnsupportedOperation`, `IllegalArgumentException`, `NullPointerException`, `ClassCastException` of `Collection#add()` method in our source code while adding a element to a collection using `add()` method?

Comment: It's better to write your code in such a way that those things won't happen. The errors you list generally indicate programming errors.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) *"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."*

Answer (score 1):

No, you should write your code so that you know they won't occur. I.e. not try to modify unmodifiable collections, since that results in `UnsupportedOperationException` etc.

Besides, how would you even handle them?

Comment: Thank you :) . As per the design smell there is a topic called "Rebellious Hierarchy" where it states that we need to handle the exception when create a object like this:
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
Below is the link
http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2013_06/article1.pdf
In the above link section 5.4.6

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you mean with "handle".

You should definitely log these exceptions **somewhere** in your application, not necessarily close to the `Collection.add()` call. Some top-level wrapper might be the much better place.

However, if you catch these exceptions (or any other exception), ask yourself "Can I continue from here normally although the `add()` wasn't successful?". From my experience, in the majority of cases, you can't - you are adding the element because that's what your algorithm needs, so it'll fail or produce wrong results. So you want to tell your caller that you cannot fulfill your task, and that means to throw an exception, or easier, to let the exception ripple through to your caller.

Only, you don't want your whole application to come to a halt because of one local programmer mistake, so a wrapper around top-level menu functions, service requests or similar things makes sense, catching and logging all Throwables, informing the user and bringing the application into a state to accept the next command / request (if that doesn't happen automatically).

So, the laziest programmer often produces the most robust code (exception-wise), because he'll never introduce unneccessary catch clauses.